# how to include two copies of crystalreports in a single page?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am developing a software in vb.net.I am using crystal report in visual studio 2010. Where I have to print two copies of Invoice in a single page.  One for customer and another is for office records. Now the problem is length of the the invoice. If it contains like 5 to 9 items then we can easily print two copies in a single page but what if it contains more than 10 items. 
Hey I am novice to crystal reports so I expect your solution in some technical terms.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Your best option is to set the font size to ensure that the 'worst-case' fits to your requirements.